# why is showing a error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

Here,i'm trying to get Structural Similarity(SSIM) between real an fake images,but got a error.
How to fix this problem?
where should be code changed?

Code for real images:

```
    def frame_1(ori_id):
        frame_1=[]
        for i in zip(ori_id):
            ori_id = os.path.join(root_dir,"{}.mp4".format(','.join(i)))
            
            #ori_id means original video

            capture_ori = cv2.VideoCapture(ori_id)
            frames_num = int(capture_ori.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) 
            for j in range(frames_num):
                capture_ori.grab()
                if j % 10 != 0:
                    continue
                success, frame_1 = capture_ori.retrieve()
                #print(frame_1)
                if not success:
                    continue
                id = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ori_id))[0]
                frame_1=[i for i in zip(frame_1)]
                frame_1.append(frame_1)
                 
        return frame_1
```

Here ori_id means root original video_path:

```
    frame_1=frame_1(ori_id)
```

Code for fakes images:

```
    def frame_2(fake_id):    
        frame_2=[]
        for i in zip(fake_id):
            fake_id = os.path.join(root_dir,"{}.mp4".format(','.join(i)))
            #fake_id means fake video
            capture_fake = cv2.VideoCapture(fake_id)
            frames_num = int(capture_fake.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
            #print(frames_num)
            for j in range(frames_num):
                capture_fake.grab()
                if j % 10 != 0:
                    continue
                success, frame_2 = capture_fake.retrieve()
                #print(frame_2)
                if not success:
                    continue
                frame_2=[i for i in zip(frame_2)]
                frame_2.append(frame_2)               
        return frame_2
```

Here fake_id means root fake video_path,

```
    frame_2=frame_2(fake_id)
```

For structural similarity(SSIM) code:

```
    d, a = compare_ssim(frame_1,frame_2, multichannel=True, full=True)
    a = 1 - a
    diff = (a * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    diff = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    diff_path='F:/deepfake_data/ssim_diff.jpg'
    #Here diff_path means save image path
    cv2.imwrite(diff_path, diff)
```

Return a error like this:

```
*AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
      
<ipython-input-15-9eecfad7aa58> in save_diffs(pair, root_dir)
    147     #..........SSIM..........................
    148     #try:
--> 149     d, a = compare_ssim(frame_1,frame_2, multichannel=True, full=True)
    150     a = 1 - a
    151     diff = (a * 255).astype(np.uint8)

F:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_structural_similarity.py in compare_ssim(X, Y, win_size, gradient, data_range, multichannel, gaussian_weights, full, **kwargs)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     if not X.shape == Y.shape:
     84         raise ValueError('Input images must have the same dimensions.')
     85 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'*
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [This piece of documentation](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/skimage.measure.compare_ssim)  compare_ssim inputs should be ndarrays.

The easy way to solve it is converting the frames in ndarrays, let's say, in the return statements, like this:

```
return np.array(frame_1)
```

and

```
return np.array(frame_2)
```

Still, I thing that this might solve this specific error, but I'm not sure if it make sense to compare a bunch of images changing over time, maybe it would be useful compare one by one

```
[compare_ssim(frame_1[i],frame_2[i]) for i in range(0, min(len(frame_1), len(frame_2)))]
```

Comment: return a error <ipython-input-17-b64a685266b1> in frame_1(ori_id)
     84                 id = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(ori_id))[0]
     85                 #frame_1=[i for i in zip(frame_1)]
---> 86                 frame_1=np.ndarray(frame_1)
     87                 frame_1.append(frame_1)
     88                 #frame_1=np.array(frame_1)

ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1080

Comment: My mistake, np.ndarray does something completely different, let's try np.array instead

Comment: Again showed a error ,whenever i add  np.array(frame_2),return a AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'